# AttributeError: 'contactObject' object has no attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror, suds

This is my function:

```
def get_content(self):
    full_results = []
    for res in self._get_data():  #function that returns suds object
        final_dict = dict(res)
        final_dict.pop('readOnlyContactData', None)
        if res["readOnlyContactData"] is not None: 
            readOnlyContactData_dict = dict(res["readOnlyContactData"])
            final_dict.update(readOnlyContactData_dict)
    full_results.append(final_dict)
    return full_results
```

However when runnning it I get:

```
INFO - if res["readOnlyContactData"] is not None:
INFO - File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 154, in __getitem__
INFO - return getattr(self, name)
INFO - AttributeError: 'contactObject' object has no attribute 'readOnlyContactData'
INFO - Command exited with return code 1
```

I don't understand why it fails the if condition is suppose to check if `res["readOnlyContactData"]` exists. if it does process it and if not ignore it.

Why this condition fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, using `variable['key']` syntax internally calls `__getitem__('key')` to retrieve the right element. In your case, the error indicates that `__getitem__()` internally calls `getattr()`, which is usually used to retrieve a class member or an instance variable.

```
File "/path/to/sudsobject.py", line 154, in __getitem__
    return getattr(self, name)
AttributeError: 'contactObject' object has no attribute 'readOnlyContactData'
```

So, based on information you provided, calling `res["readOnlyContactData"]` seems equivalent to call `res.readOnlyContactData`. Since `readOnlyContactData` attribute is not found in your object (of type `contactObject`), you get this error.

Try the following statements to check wether your object has the member you are looking for or not:

```
>>> # this has to be implemented in your class
>>> "readOnlyContactData" in res
```

or

```
>>> hasattr(res, "readOnlyContactData")
```

Answer (score 1):

That if condition checks whether the element residing in `res["readOnlyContactData"]` is `None` or not. So, if `res` does not have any index named `"readOnlyContactData"` Python returns the exception `Object has no attribute`. Instead of the if-statement you should try `hasattr(res, "readOnlyContactData")`